# Automation of pivot chart in excel 2007

Tags: ruby, excel, autoit, win32ole

Could you please help me in order to automate a pivot chart, below is the code which I had written. I'm currently stuck creating a chart

```
require "rubygems"
# require "watir" # Commented out by editor to the question, not by the OP
require 'win32ole'

excel=WIN32OLE.new("Excel.Application")
excel.visible=true
work_book=excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\VAMSI\\PIVOTAL_CHART_CODE\\pivotal.xlsx")
worksheet = work_book.worksheets(1)
worksheet.range("a1").select
autoit= WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
autoit.Send("!n")
autoit.Send("!v")
autoit.Send("!t")
autoit.Send("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Watir. Watir drives browsers. You want to drive Excel. This could help: [Automating Excel with Ruby](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/03/automating-excel-with-ruby.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Željko Filipin, i know that this is not related to watir, and i had done excel automation for few things, but here i would like to create a pivot chart, and don't 've idea to do this.

Comment: I have no idea what a pivot chart is. If you knew the question was not related to Watir, why did you tag it watir? :)

Comment: it should not be tagged in to watir, its completely about win32ole object, the question is how to automate Micorsoft Excel pivot chart with ruby :)

Comment: Well, the only tag it had when you asked the question was watir. I have changed it to what it is now. You can add/edit/delete tags.

Comment: @Vam: You also originally had "watir" in the title, and you had `"require "watir"` in your code.

Comment: just removed the line require "watir" in my code as its not required for this task.

Answer (score 1):

Go into excel and record a macro in which you create a pivot chart. Then look at the macro source code and convert it to ruby or AutoIt or watir or whatever else you feel like using...